# Overset \Rightarrow and \Leftarrow

Tags: arrows, ctan

I need a couple non-standard arrows for a paper that I'm writing.
I need a `\Rightarrow` and `\Leftarrow` that are set like `$\overrightarrow{A}$` and `$\underleftarrow{B}$`. I was able to find the package [overrightarrow](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/overrightarrow) on CTAN, but I do not have the know how to get an analogue for `$\Leftarrow$`.

Can anyone help? Do you know a package with these arrows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the purpose of just putting a double arrow on something there are two easy ways: the `\overset` macro from `amsmath`, and `\accentset` from the `accents` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} % for \overset
\usepackage{accents} % for \accentset

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb+\accentset+               & $\accentset{\Rightarrow}{A}$ \\
\verb+\overset+                 & $\overset{\Rightarrow}{A}$ \\
\verb+\overset+ (with tweaking) & $\overset{\,\Rightarrow\!}{A}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\accentset` sets the "accent" in `\scriptscriptstyle` and takes the skew of the character into account. The "accent" from `\overset` is somewhat larger (`\scriptstyle`) and needs a wee bit of tweaking to be properly placed.

If the arrow need to be extensible, a quick look to `amsmath` (lines 907ff) helps. There, some extensible arrows are set up but not all of them have a user-level macro. According to a comment from Barbara Beeton

> `amsmath` was created when memory space for macro names was severely
>   limited. so only the absolutely necessary minimum was frozen into the
>   package, and it was assumed that users could define additions by
>   analogy

So we can define by analogy

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
% cf. amsmath.sty lines 907-920
\newcommand*{\overRightarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\Rightarrowfill@}}
\newcommand*{\overLeftarrow}{\mathpalette{\overarrow@\Leftarrowfill@}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\overRightarrow{ABCD}$ \quad $\overRightarrow{\!ABCD\,\,}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that also here we might need to manually add some spaces.

In the hope the author the package `overrightarrow` won't resent me too much, I would discourage from using it. The package relies on a macro `\overarrow@` which isn't defined. It is defined in `amsmath`, but calling this before `overrightarrow` will raise an error, and reversing the order the definition of further macros will be overwritten. There might be a meaningful way of using `overrightarrow` but, alas, I could not find it. (Which is most surely my shortcoming.)

Comment: `amsmath` was created when memory space for macro names was severely limited.  so only the absolutely necessary minimum was frozen into the package, and it was assumed that users could define additions by analogy.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I wanted to add a couple of details into the answer. May I incorporate you comment?

Comment: oh, you are quite welcome to incorporate my comment.  (maybe it turns out that the assumption was a bit optimistic, but 25 years ago, who knew?)

Comment: Thanks for this. I finally started to write the paper using these suggestions, and it all worked great. Needed to extend to "underRightarrow" and "underLeftarrow" but that was a piece of cake because of the carefully reference to amsmath.sty.